# Best Practice for storing DateTime values in Xpages

Tags: xpages

I'm trying to implement Managed Beans that represent objects with some date-time values (It's a Training session, with a day, a start time and an end-time).

I am not sure what is the best practice for actually storing the information within my Java code - a Vector, a Java Time object, a lotus.domino.notesdatetime.

I've been badly burnt before and I was wondering what is the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store each date-time-value in a **java.util.Date** object.

You can get the Date value from NotesDateTime value with `.toJavaDate()`

Comment: For your example you showed in a comment you'd use: `this.schulungstag = schulungstagvector.get(0).toJavaDate()`

Comment: I was up to this DateTime schulungstagDateTime = null;

  schulungstagDateTime = (DateTime) TerminDoc
      .getItemValueDateTimeArray("SchulungsTag");

    setSchulungstag(schulungstagDateTime.toJavaDate());

    try {
    if (schulungstagDateTime != null) {
     schulungstagDateTime.recycle();
    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: Be prepared for issues related to DLS and time zones for times close to midnight, though.

Comment: Aah Knut, I've also discovered that just giving a EL handle to the method gives the correct format, and I can format it really easily. So cool! I thought I'd have to deliver the HTML myself. I cannot for the life of me understand why IBM decided that we were all too stupid to use Java and went through all the effort of SSJS and translated @Formulas.

Answer (score 2):

Use the OpenNTF Domino API and then you can basically ignore the lotus.domino.DateTime class and work strictly with the Java objects.

Side note: You should never use a Vector for anything, really. They are a concrete holdover in the lotus.domino API from Java 1.1.

Comment: Nathan, thanks for your answer. the Domino API is seducing - I would love not to have to recycle every single Domino object. But I have a prickly administrator who doesn't like installing anything new. And I agree with you on the Vector object being horrible.